# UICollectionView stops accepting tap gestures after interacting with a UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview, uitextfield

I have a horizontal UICollectionView with square cells that allows single selection only and a UITextField above it. Collection view is configured like so:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout* flowLayout = [UICollectionViewFlowLayout new];
flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = kCellSpacing;
flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = kCellSpacing;
flowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(kCellWidth, kCellWidth);

self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
self.collectionView.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor3].CGColor;
self.collectionView.layer.cornerRadius = kCornerRadius;
self.collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
self.collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = NO;
self.collectionView.bounces = NO;
self.collectionView.exclusiveTouch = YES;
[self addSubview:self.collectionView];
```

Code for textField:

```
_amountTextField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
_amountTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
_amountTextField.font = [_amountTextField.font fontWithSize:26.0];
_amountTextField.textField.delegate = self;
[self addSubview:_amountTextField];
```

`UICollectionViewCells` are properly configured - subviews are added either to contentView or backgroundView, userInteraction is disabled on each subview so that the gestures are passed to superview.

### **The issue:**

I'm experiencing the weirdest issue after selecting and deselecting the textfield: **my UICollectionView stops responding to selecting cells**. I've managed to determine that highlighting works fine and sometimes (this is pretty much indeterminate) allows for selection as well.

If I do a long press on a cell the delegate methods are called in following order:

```
-(BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView shouldHighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didHighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and sometimes

```
-(BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Scrolling the collectionView's scrollview is also working.

This is pretty much all I can share about the issue. I would really appreciate some help. Googling and searching stackoverflow yielded no usable results.

Comment: can you please provide snapshot of you collection view, how you designed

Comment: @SagarSnehi Unfortunatelly this is not possible, but i can describe it to you:

We have a horizontal UICollectionView which is about 50 points high and stretches from left to right, cells are also 50x50pts so that only ~5-7 cells are displayed at once. The collection view itself contains about 15-20 cells. The rest is described in the code for the collectionviewflowlayout.

Comment: Where you added textField

Comment: As stated in the description: textfield is added above the collection view. They're on the same level of the view hierarchy, but have different superviews. Their superviews have a common parent.

Comment: Could it be that the `collectionView`s superview has its `userInteraction` disabled after you deselect the `UITextField`?

Comment: @Rikh I dont't think so that's the case. As I said, scrolling and highlighting works properly. The tap gesture is the only issue.

Answer (score 0):

OK, thanks for all of your input guys. The problem was the `UITapGestureRecognizer` that was added to main superview after `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` was received and not properly removed after receiving `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`. After fixing that everything works like a charm! Thanks!